# After return the value from function then json_encode is not working

Tags: php, json

I have two functions. First `contact function` and second  `sendmail function`.  After submitting the form First it will submit the data and then `sendmail` function will send the email.

Both scenarios are working. I am getting some issues with my sendmail function.  I mean I am getting the return value from sendmail function but my `echo json_encode($response)` not working.

I am getting the output on my network tab.

```
Message accepted{"error":"Data Inserted","error_no":"11"}
```

If I comment my sendmail function then it's working.

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        url:base_url+"/process.php",
        type: "post",
        data: e,
        contentType: false,
        cache:false,
        processData:false,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(response) {
           //alert(response.error_no);
            if (response.error_no == '1'){
                 $('#name').html(response.error);
              }
             //some more else
              else if(response.error_no == 11){
                  window.location.href=base_url+"/thankyou";
              }
              else{
                  window.location.href=base_url+"/thankyou";
              }
        }
    })
```

**Process.php**

```
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

   switch ($action) {
       case 'contact_fun' : contact_fun($conn); break;
       default : header('Location: index.php'); 
   }
function contact_fun($conn){
//all validation code here

      else {
        $query="INSERT INTO `tbl_requestform` (name, email, mobileno,img) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        if($stmt=$conn->prepare($query)) {
          $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $mobno, $img);
          $stmt->execute();

          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $errorMsg="Data Inserted";
            $code="11";
            $_SESSION['thankyouSession']="true";
          }
          else {
            $code="11";
            $errorMsg='Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.';
            $_SESSION['thankyouSession']="true";
          }
        }
        else {
          $code="12";
          $errorMsg='Poor Network Connection';
        }
        $sendmail=sendemail_to_admin($conn, $name, $email, $mobno, $img);

     $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
      }
      $response['error']=$errorMsg;
      $response['error_no']=$code;
      echo json_encode($response);
    }

    function sendemail_to_admin($conn, $name, $email, $mobno, $img) {
      //all my email code here
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "Message accepted";
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        echo "Error: Message not accepted";
      }
    }
```

Comment: why not use return instead of echo ?

Comment: Show how you call these functions.

Comment: @u_mulder, after submitting the button, I am sending the action value in the switch case. Code updated. and sendmail function is already added in the contact_fun.

Comment: @danish-khan-I, Where I have to use return? In the sendmail function, I already added return 1.

Comment: So the problem is?

Comment: @u_mulder, Problem is,I am inserting the data using ajax so after sending the email echo json_encode($response) not call back.

Comment: @u_mulder, I updated my ajax code. It's not redirecting.

Comment: So remove output of `Meesage accepted`.

Comment: @u_mulder, oh!..right. It's working. I wasted my 3 hours to find the solution and you solved in 5 mins. Thanks for the help.